# Get rad scheduler day end time and day start time in client side

Tags: telerik, radscheduler

How to get telerik rad schedulers day end time and day start time in client side on "OnClientAppointmentMoveEnd" event

Answer (score 0):

As per my understating, You want new start time of appointment. 
Let me know if i am not understand your requirement.

Please try with the below code snippet.

JS

```
function ClientAppointmentMoveEnd(sender, args) {
            var _OldtartDate = args.get_appointment()._start;
            var _OldEndDate = args.get_appointment()._end;
            var _NewStartDate = args.get_newStartTime();
        }
```

ASPX

```
<telerik:RadScheduler ID="RadScheduler1" runat="server" OnClientAppointmentMoveEnd="ClientAppointmentMoveEnd">
</telerik:RadScheduler>
```

Answer (score 0):

'Day end time' and 'Day start time' of the Rad Scheduler can access in the client side by following way:

```
function OnClientAppointmentMoveEnd(sender, args)
{
     var scheduleStart = sender.get_activeModel().get_visibleRangeStart();
     var scheduleEnd = sender.get_activeModel().get_visibleRangeEnd();
}
```